# ¿Como puedo sumar datos de tipo Time en PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero sumar datos de tipo tiempo en Laravel y mostrarlo en cantidad de horas, por lo que decidí pasarlo todo a segundos y de ahí dividirlo por 3600 con la función Round(). El código funciona pero por alguna razón da una suma errónea, si cambio los datos o introduzco más la suma también lo hace, pero no logro identificar cual es mi error. Si no utilizo la función round me da   4.2827777777778.

Estos es el código del controller:

```
    static function noCero(){
    $fechas=Fecha::all(); 
    $objetivos=Objetivo::all();
    $objetivosCount=Objetivo::all()->count();
    $datos=Dato::all();
    $datosCount=Dato::all()->count();

    foreach($objetivos as $tiempoObj){
        foreach($objetivos as $tiempoObj){
            foreach($tiempoObj->fNombreObj as $fno){
                $horas[] = $fno->tiempo;}
            }
    }
    $total = 0;
    foreach($horas as $h) {
        $parts = explode(":", $h);
        $total += $parts[2] + $parts[1]*60 + $parts[0]*3600;        
    }   
    $totalHoras = round($total/3600);
    return view('noCero', compact('datos', 'objetivos','fechas','objetivosCount', 'totalHoras'));
```

Y estas son las vistas:

```
<table class="table">
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
    <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <th>{{$obj->nombre}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        @foreach($fechas as $fecha)
            <tr>
                    <td>{{$fecha->fecha}}</td>
                @foreach($fecha->objetivos as $tiempoObjetivo)
                    @if($tiempoObjetivo->tiempo > "01:00:00")
                        <td style="color:green;">{{$tiempoObjetivo->tiempo}}</td>
                    @else
                        <td style="color:red;">{{$tiempoObjetivo->tiempo}}</td>
                    @endif

                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'route' => 'objetivos.store']) !!}
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            {!!Form::date('fecha')!!}
                        </td>
                    @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
                        <td>
                            {!! Form::time('tiempo[]') !!}    
                            {!!Form::hidden('obj_id[]', $obj->id)!!}
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">{!!Form::submit('Agregar datos de hoy')!!}</td>
                </tr>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
    <tr>
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET', 'url' => '/createObj']) !!}
            <td>{!!Form::text('nombre')!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::submit('Agregar objetivo')!!}</td>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </tr>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
    <tr>
            <td></td>
            @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
                <td>{{$totalHoras}}</td>
            @endforeach
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Estos son los datos que son sumados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Así es como se ve la página, abajo está la suma de las horas]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por las dudas hacé un ``dd($horas)` antes de `$total` para ver realmente que se está guardando en ese array. El código parece correcto. Como alternativa podes usar [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) para sumar los tiempos, ya que estás usando Laravel.

Comment: Acabo de subir una foto del dd(), voy a analizar un momento por que es que las guarda así...

Comment: Tenés el  `foreach ($objetivos as $tiempoObj)` repetido, uno adentro del otro. Por eso se repiten las entradas.

Comment: Por otro lado, ojo con como definís `$objetivosCount` y `$datosCount`, estás haciendo una 2da llamada en cada uno innecesaria. Si ya trajiste todos los resultados en `$objetivos` y `$datos`, no los vuelvas a traer, contá lo que ya tenés: `$objetivosCount = $objetivos->count()`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, en serio!